# how do I send colors to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an assignment for school (mobile device applications programming) and I've run into an issue. Part of the assignment is to create an ArrayList of colors and then use a random number generator to randomly select a color set (for both text and background color) and apply it to the TextView. I am not sure I am populating the array properly. The parameters are set in a class called Colors_Class() I will include the class code as well as the method for populating the array here. I appreciate any and all help. thanks

here is the code for the Class

```
public class Color_Class 
{
private int backgroundColor;
private int textColor;

public Color_Class(int color, int background)
{
    textColor = color;
    backgroundColor = background;
}
public int Get_Background_Color()
{
    return backgroundColor;
}
public int Get_Text_Color()
{
    return textColor;
}

}
```

Here is the method code

```
private void Create_Color_Objects() 
{


    Color_Class color1 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"),     Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    colorObjectList.add(color1);

    Color_Class color2 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#FFe4c4"));
    colorObjectList.add(color2);

    Color_Class color3 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"), Color.parseColor("#SF9EA0"));
    colorObjectList.add(color3);

    Color_Class color4 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#8A2BE2"));
    colorObjectList.add(color4);

    Color_Class color5 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#FF7F24"), Color.parseColor("#7FFF00"));
    colorObjectList.add(color5);

    Color_Class color6 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#DC143C"));
    colorObjectList.add(color6);

    Color_Class color7 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#00008B"), Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"));
    colorObjectList.add(color7);

    Color_Class color8 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#8B6508"), Color.parseColor("#A9A9A9"));
    colorObjectList.add(color8);

    Color_Class color9 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#8B0000"));
    colorObjectList.add(color9);

    Color_Class color10 = new Color_Class(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#8B3A3A"));
    colorObjectList.add(color10);




}
```

Comment: Why do you think tha array is being populated incorrectly? Where is colorObjectList being defined? Have you initialized it to an empty ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, it would be better if you can use a generic version of your array list:

```
ArrayList<Color_Class> colorObjectList = new ArrayList<Color_Class>();
```

Comment: if he hasn't covered generics in class he *might* get in trouble for using it in an assignment

Comment: you are corrct edthethird, the arraylist has to be like I have it for this assignment, but thank you Hasanein for the comment. If the problem is not in how I am populating the list, then it must be in how I am trying to access the list. The assignment calls for me to use a random number generator to generate a number between 0-9 and then use that number to select a color from the array and apply it to the TextView.

Comment: @tmwebdeveloper You still haven't explained the problem you're having. You tell us the problem you have to solve but you don't tell us the exact problem you're having trying to solve the general problem. Tell us what you're trying, what you're expecting, and what's actually happening. Expend a little energy.

Comment: @AHungerArtist I apologize for not being thorough in my explanation. I would have replied sooner but I work full time as well as attend college full time. I did find the problem with my program. The ArrayList was fine and how I was calling it was fine, however I was calling the random number generator method in the wrong place (didn't have it in the onCreate method. Thanks to you and the others who promptly replied offering your help last night. The next time I have a question I will be sure to be more thorough in explaining the issue. Thanks again!